# Selecting the rows with min value for a field, where the rest of fields differ

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write SQL (Access 2010) to select parts which have a minimum price from a table where the parts can repeat, as some of the other fields are different.

The table that looks like this:

```
Dist Part Num  Ven Part Num     Dist  Desc                Price
DD7777QED      7777QED          DD    Product A              10
IM7777QED      7777QED          IM    This is Product A      12
SY7777QED      7777QED          SY    Product A Desc         15
DD8888QED      8888QED          DD    Product B              15
IM8888QED      8888QED          IM    This is Product B      10
SY8888QED      8888QED          SY    Product B Desc         12
IM999ABC       999ABC           IM    Product C Desc         15
```

I am trying to extract all details for each row that has the min price for that Ven Part Num that repeats. In essence all details for the supplier's row that has the cheapest price for that Vendor Part Number.

The result from the above sample data should be this:

```
Dist Part Num  Ven Part Num     Dist   Desc               Price
DD7777QED      7777QED          DD     Product A             10
IM8888QED      8888QED          IM     This is Product A     10
IM999ABC       999ABC           IM     Product A Desc        15
```

Thanks

EDIT: Thank you jurgen d for your answer, although I think you meant to use Ven Part Num (instead of Dist Part Num). I have ammended to this query now which almost works to what I want:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM My_Table T1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT [Ven Part Num], MIN(Price) AS MPrice
   FROM My_Table
   GROUP BY [Ven Part Num]
) T2 ON T1.[Ven Part Num] = T2.[Ven Part Num] AND T1.Price = T2.MPrice
```

Challenge now is that if two Dist have the same MIN price for the same Ven Part Num, then the resulting extract contains 2 rows for that Ven Part Num, but I want just one, either will do. I tried TOP 1 but it runs and brings up only one row as result of the whole query. I have 40K rows I am expecting! How do I extract only one of these two rows in the final report?

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I dint get, you saying tat Dist is a unique key, then how could it repeat, there is IM in 3 records

Comment: Hi Md. Parvez Alam, the Dist_Part_Num is unique key (it does not repeat). Juergen d's answer seems close as I think he mistook Dist_Part_Num with Ven_Part_Num. Once I make this change I end up close to the result. Only issue is where two Dist rows (different Dist) contain the same Ven_Part_Num at the same MIN price... I get the two rows, where I really want any of the two, so only one row extracted. Do you know how I can filter to one row?

Comment: Try distinct keyword in inner query

Comment: Hi Md. Parvez Alam, thanks for the suggestion, but it did not make a difference, as the two rows returned are distinct in every aspect except for Ven Part Num and Price.

Comment: did u use like SELECT distinct [Ven Part Num], MIN(Price) AS MPrice in inner query, as only these two columns are being fetched in the inner query so i think it should work

Comment: Hi Md. Parvez Alam, yes I did, and I think the reason for two rows coming back in the final result is that two suppliers (so different content of other fields) with the same Ven Part Num, and same MIN MPrice appear as the rows themselves are distinct from each other. The Distinct in the sub query is retrieving only one of each Ven Part Num but the external query is using these Ven Part Num & Min Price to find all rows which match, so two Dists with same Ven Part Num & Min Price will appear.

Comment: do one thing from inner query select only Dist Part Num and in outer condition add in clause, i mean to say you have unique Dist Part Num, so form inner query you will get only desired Dist Part Num, and in outer query you can fetch record from within those Dist Part Num

Comment: or other alternate could be something like this SELECT T1.* 
FROM My_Table T1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT distinct [Dist Part Num],[Ven Part Num], MIN(Price) AS MPrice
   FROM My_Table
   GROUP BY [Ven Part Num]
) T2 ON T1.[Ven Part Num] = T2.[Ven Part Num] AND T1.Price = T2.MPrice and Ti.Dist Part Num in (t2.Dist Part Num)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
inner join 
(
   select [Dist Part Num], min(price) as mprice
   from your_table
   group by [Dist Part Num]
) t2 on t1.[Dist Part Num] = t2.[Dist Part Num] and t1.price = t2.mprice
```

Comment: Hi Juergen d,Thanks for the fast reply! I tried your quesry but I am getting Vendor Part Num values repeated... In essence, the Vendor Part Num should appear once in the report but contain the lowest price and all details from the supplier selling it... Your query is not something I have done before, so no wonder I was stuck! Do you have any suggestion on what to check as to why the result would be as I am getting? Thanks!